# Long response times vs. concurrency issues on a multithreaded web server

Tags: .net, multithreading, server

A class with a slow initialization used to process a request leads to long response times. But the actual method used is *quite* fast. Should the class be static, I guess it would need to process a request at a time. **So, what would be the best way of combating the long initialization time while not bottlenecking the requests?**

A bit of background. The class initialises a Python subprocess and pipes the `stdin` and `stdout`. It loads a heavy library and a largish amount of data for computation, hence the slow initialization. The pipe is what I'm concerned about, as I'm expecting a line of response for a line of input.

Thoughts, ideas? I'm open to even modifying the approach if it's needed to accomplish this better. I'm pretty new to web services and have been thrown in deep, so any insight is greatly appreciated.

If it matters, I'm on VB/C#.NET.

Comment: can you turn the Python software from a single-use program to a kind of service than can respond to multiple requests? The pipe or the class constructor isn't the problem, starting a Python process per request is.

Comment: @amon It's not exactly single-use. The pipe is open for as long as needed and it's processed line by line. So, what do you mean?

Comment: I think @amon means something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the class be static

No. Instantiate and initalise the class when the app starts and pass it in to other classes which depend on it.

Inorder to synchronise the calls over threads, preventing input, input, output, output instead of input, output, input, output , the class itself will need to use a SemaphoreSlim or Mutex internally.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! To my (very limited) knowledge, the classes that handle a request are either instantiated per request, or the methods are some kind of static method e.g. hinted with `<Route "foo">`. How do I pass it in?

Comment: is it a .net webapi or mvc site? you can use unity DI and registerinstance to instanciate a single object instead of one per request and pass it in through constructor injection on your controllers

Comment: I have a feeling you may well want more than one of these objects for optimal performance, due to the io constraint. similar to having more than one command window open at the same time.

Comment: It may very well be... God I'm in too deep :D Maybe I'll just try to look into it before wasting your time. But thank you very much, I'll investigate and get back.

Answer (score 0):

> Should the class be static?

Yes, but with a caveat.  You must ensure that the method being called in the Python subprocess doesn't not alter state whatsoever, or if state is altered, it can handle concurrent calls.

If this isn't your case, you can still make it static, provided you put the actual call to python in a synchronized block to ensure only one thread is making the request at a time.

Consider extracting the Python initialization and putting it in its own handling class, and using it to perform any and all calls to Python.  Ideally you would then use dependency injection to add it to your class for use.